# Если функции Oracle возвращает package

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Пишу приложение webJava
В базе Oracle
Имею доступ к нескольким пакетам (точнее к их синонимам), с процедурами и функциями.

Есть функция в пакете INFO_PKG

```
FUNCTION GET_TASKS RETURNS INFO_PKG
 Argument Name   Type         In/Out Default?
 ------------- -------------- ------ --------
 ID               VARCHAR2      IN
 NAME             VARCHAR2      IN
 TIMESTAMP        DATE          IN
```

Эта функция возвращает сам пакет. Как это использовать?

Comment: в инете много мануалов по PL/SQL, но об этом я информацию не нашел.

Comment: А вы уверены, что это пакет, а не объект  ?

Comment: Не уверен. Как проверить что за данные там?

Comment: посмотреть в user_objects я думаю их там должно быть видно и будет видно что они такое

Comment: OBJECT_NAME = INFO_PKG;  OBJECT_TYPE = SYNONYM;  STATUS=VALID; И еще несколько таких же

Comment: тогда посмотрите на что этот синоним (в user_synonyms) и узнайте наконец что за объект

Comment: Ссылается на другого пользователя. synonym_name=INFO_PKG; table_owner=OTHER_USER; table_name=INFO_PKG; Через SQL Developer смотрю те же самые пакеты в package. открыть не могу выдает ошибку ORA-01460. Через SQLPlus вижу в этих пакетах (синонимы)  функции и процедуры. одна из них нужная мне выше.

Comment: ну теперь опять в user_objects там должны быть и объекты OTHER_USER

Comment: у меня очень ограниченные права

Comment: ну если вы его не видите, то тут говорить в общем то не о чем. мне кажется что это не пакет, а объектный тип и возврат SELF для него в порядке вещей

Comment: Спасибо что помогаете. Разобрался ошибка у меня  - SQL Developer со старой базой не полноценно работает. у другого пользователя я вижу что это теже названия и это пакеты. но функция возвращает то же название (как пакет), это о чем говорит? может как то командой посмотреть у другого юзера описание этой функции в пакете? потому что так как у меня синоним я не вижу описание функции. или подскажете команду какой запрос можно выполнить чтобы в чем то убедиться.

Comment: У SQL Developer же есть свои средства просмотра. Object browser по идее должен показывать любые доступные для просмотра объекты

Comment: Вот я и говорю что у другого пользователя вижу что это пакеты. Мне не понятно одно почему функция в пакете INFO_PKG возвращает то же название INFO_PKG что это? Тут еще есть информация для вас. В этих пакетах некоторые процедуры принимают параметры IN/OUT с типом INFO_PKG. Как узнать как с этим типом работать. (просто смутило одинаковое название с пакетом)

Comment: SQL Developer не дает мне посмотреть на пакеты (ORA-01460). Вроде из за того что версия оракла слишком старая для программы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось найти в all_source пакт INFO_PKG и там такой кусочек

```
TYPE info IS RECORD{
  name varchar2(30),
  user_id number,
  e_time date
};

TYPE infos IS TABLE OF info; 

FUNCTION get_tasks (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2, timestamp DATE)
RETURN info_pkg.infos
PIPELINED;
```

Теперь с возвращаемыми типами все стало на свои места.

Но возник другой вопрос как это получить в Java. Говорят JDBC не поддерживает тип RECORD. Или то что это конвейерная функция все меняет.

Comment: Да, конвейерная функция меняет дело. Ей нужен объект и по прототипу рекорда будет создан объект с системным именем - SYS_...